# Can I get flow interview details using APEX/Metadata/Tooling API for any specific record?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, metadata-api, tooling-api

My Use case:

1. I have created a trigger flow on Lead to run after 3 days of lead creation.
2. I want to show the interview status in a LWC component
3. Users can pause/reschedule interviews from the LWC component.

My question is,

1. Can I get the current running status of in-flows Interview via APEX/Metadata/Tooling API?
2. Can I pause/resume or reschedule Interview using APEX, MetaData or Tooling API

Thanks,

Comment: Flow Interviews are data, not metadata - see [FlowInterview](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_flowinterview.htm?q=flowInterview)

Comment: Thanks @cropredy, Seems this store only erroed and paused flow interview data.